# Godot HTML5 graphics not rendering correctly

Tags: godot

I am having some issues with the HTML5. The version I am using of Godot is 3.2.3.

It should look like this:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8HPE.jpg [How the game should look, in all its glory :p]

But when I open it on my local server, it looks like this:
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZT2l.jpg [How the game looks, in all its glitchness :p]

What could be causing this?

It is also skipping the login scene when I run it on browsers. The exe version runs a-okay.

Comment: Which GLES version are you using?

Comment: I am using GLES3

Comment: That's probably the issue - you'll need to change to GLES2 for HTML5 for now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GLES2 Is the recommended graphics driver for HTML5 games with Godot! Hope this helps! More About the differences between the two graphics drivers can be found: [here](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/misc/gles2_gles3_differences.html)

Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but the problem with that seems to be that there is some screen space post process filter enabled like SSAO.
GLES3 is better on some sides but comes with a few issues for HTML